# Flutter circular border in percentage

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Is there any way to show border of percentage. I have `Container` with circle shape.

For example: whole circle is 100% and I want show only 65% of circle, something like a clock and minute hand.

Comment: Give a look to this library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/percent_indicator from  @diegoveloper

Comment: Easiest way is to use some external library. Or you can make necessary customization on your code, e.g. using `CustomClipper`, if you'll want to

Answer (score 0):

[CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) widget can handle this. To display 65%, it should look something similar to:

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
  value: 0.65,
),
```